# Goal Creation Issue in Matomo

Tags: matomo

This is regarding goal creation in Matomo
We are using Matomo open source and data is saved in our cloud platform.

The current issue is, the goal creation is not consistent. When we try to create more goals, sometimes the goal is getting created but sometimes it fails. What could be the reason for the failure. Any insights on this issue will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and delete tmp/cache/tracker/ folder and see if that resolves the issue?

In most cases clearing the cache folder above will resolve this sort of issue.